# How to create a page that edits the profiles of users with laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, view, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel, and would like to create a page that edits the profiles of users, including that of editing profile description, url and profile image.

However, I'm getting an error that states:

> 'ErrorException Attempt to read property "description" on null  (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myprojectname\resources\views\user\edit.blade.php)'

My routes in web.php are:

```
Route::get('/users/{user}/edit', [UserController::class, 'edit']);

Route::patch('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
```

My methods in UserController are:

```
public function show(User $user)
{
  return view('user.profile', ['user' => $user]);
}

public function edit(User $user)
{
    return view('user.edit', ['user' => $user]);
}

public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $data = request()->validate([
            'description' => '',
            'url' => '',
            'image' => '',
            ]);

    $user->profile->update($data);

    return redirect('/users/{$user->id}');
}
```

And finally, my form in edit.blade.php file is as follow:

```
<form action="/users/{{ $user->id }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
              @csrf
              @method('PATCH')

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="description" class="edit_description_label">Description</label>

                  <div class="edit_description_div">
                      <input id="description"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control @error('description') is-invalid @enderror"
                      name="description"
                      value="{{ old('description') ?? $user->profile->description }}"
                      autocomplete="description" autofocus>

                      @error('description')
                      <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      @enderror
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="url" class="edit_title_label">URL</label>

                  <div class="edit_url_div">
                      <input id="url"
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control @error('url') is-invalid @enderror"
                      name="url" 
                      value="{{ $user->profile->url }}"
                      autocomplete="url" autofocus>

                      @error('url')
                      <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      @enderror
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="create_post_image_div">
                <label for="image" class="create_image_label">Profile Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="image" name="image">

                @error('image')
                <div class="invalid-feedback-div">
                  <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </div>
                @enderror

                <div class="create_post_btn_div">
                  <button class="create_post_btn">Save Profile</button>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
```

I already defined the relationship in User.php model:

```
public function profile()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }
```

And did the inverse in Profile.php model:

```
public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

Again, The error I'm getting is:

> ErrorException Attempt to read property "description" on null  (View:
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myprojectname\resources\views\user\edit.blade.php)

How can  I resolve this issue to allow users to add and edit a profile description, url or profile image?

Comment: `$user->profile` is null. Does all users already have a profile?  How you defined that relationship?

Comment: I already defined the relationship in User.php model:  public function profile()
    {
      return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

Comment: I also did the inverse in Profile.php model: public function user()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

Comment: I think you'll have to use another coalescing operator. Something like `old('description') ?? ($user->profile-->description ?? '')`

Comment: Or with a ternary operator `old('description') ?? ($user->profile? $user->profile-->description: '')`

Comment: thanks so much for your help porloscerros, i tried: old('description') ?? ($user->profile->description ?? '', and it worked. Turns out, i only needed to add ?? ''